# How to most efficiently load jQuery plugin files?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, bandwidth

I am using a number of jQuery plugins. Is it more efficient to reference them separately in the master page, or should I lump the contents of each file into a single jQueryPlugins.js file and reference that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not more effecient.

Opening and Closing TCP connections is more expensive in terms of bandwidth, than downloading content while a connection has been established.

You most likely want to lump it in a file as well as minify it, using either [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) or [Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) when referencing it.

<strike>Moreover, if you wanted to get hyper conscious of your bandwidth, you could include the minified content inline within `<script type="text/javascript"> </script>` tags inside of your page.</strike> revisiting this after a while.. this is wrong; @cameron has pointed out the reason.

Note also: once the user has downloaded the single file, provided you have set up the appropriate [Expires Header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), your code will be cached. That way you don't have to worry about referencing other files within your site or performance x-site.

Comment: I wouldn't embed the framework JavaScript directly inside `<script>` tags in the page if I were you -- it eliminates the possibility of caching, necessitating that the same JavaScript be downloaded with every page request (and not just the first one).

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate solution depends on your circumstances. A single file will reduce HTTP connections, decreasing latency. However, you may end up with wasted band-width.

It's a trade off you will need to determine.